# ASP.NET ADODB RecordSet looping

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, adodb

So I'm trying to loop through each row of a ADODB recordset just that the recordset.movenext() stops halfway with error EOF
After i pass this error
My table has 95520 rows and Numverif holds the value : 47760
so it iterates only halfway

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim numverif As Integer = 0
con.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=xxxx.xx.xx.xxxx;Database=nameOfDB;Uid=user;Pwd=pass")
RecSet.Open("select * from table1", con, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, 1)
count.Text = RecSet.GetString(StringFormatEnum.adClipString, 10, " _ ", Environment.NewLine, "null")

Do While Not RecSet.EOF
    Dim IdontCareAboutThisVariable As String = RecSet.GetString(StringFormatEnum.adClipString, 1, "`", , "NULL")
    numverif= numverif + 1
    'The next line throws the error
    RecSet.MoveNext()
Loop
con.Close()
count.Text = numverif.ToString
```

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Could it be that `GetString` automatically does a `MoveNext`?

Comment: I removed the RecSet.MoveNext() statement and now it works fine a bit slow but its ok .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim numverif As Integer = 0
    con.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=xxxx.xx.xx.xxxx;Database=nameOfDB;Uid=user;Pwd=pass")
    RecSet.Open("select * from table1", con, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, 1)
    count.Text = RecSet.GetString(StringFormatEnum.adClipString, 10, " _ ", Environment.NewLine, "null")

    Do While Not RecSet.EOF
        Dim IdontCareAboutThisVariable As String = RecSet.GetString(StringFormatEnum.adClipString, 1, "`", , "NULL")
        numverif= numverif + 1
    Loop
    con.Close()
    count.Text = numverif.ToString
```